# appendTo() is not a function?

Tags: jquery

I thought this code should work but it didnt, can someone explain?

```
 $("#addLinkLayout input.comment, #addLinkLayout input.link").each(function() {
      $(this).val().appendTo('div#links');
 });
```

It says `$(this).val().appendTo()` is not a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`appendTo` can only be applied on jQuery objects. But `val` returns a string.

Try this instead:

```
$("#addLinkLayout input.comment, #addLinkLayout input.link").each(function() {
    $('div#links').append($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`val()` doesn't return a DOM element.  It returns the `value` attribute from a DOM element.  So if you have something like `<input value="foo" />`, calling val() on that node will give you a string `"foo"`.  Since javascript's string class doesn't have a method `appendTo`, you're getting an error.

You probably want something like

```
$('div#links').append($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

val returns a string, not a jQuery object, try:

```
$('div#links').append($(this).val());
```

Answer (score 1):

$(this).val() doesn't return a jQuery object (it returns the value of the input element). So it can't be chained.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to

```
$("#addLinkLayout input.comment, #addLinkLayout input.link").each(function() {
  $('div#links').append($(this).val());
});
```